# How to handle 'Waiting for the application under test' in Microsoft Test Manager 2015 Update 1

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager

Has anyone seen this issue before in Microsoft Test Manager? I have closed the application being tested, re-opened it and still the message appears (and Test Manager is essentially hung up on it).

It happens somewhat randomly (too often for me) but when it does I have no choice but to kill the Test Manager process and start my test all over again.I am not sure what happens to cause this issue in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been an issue both in 2013 and 2015 version, and I have not found a good (permanent) solution (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780934/error-message-in-mtm-waiting-for-the-application-under-test)

If I disable everything in run settings/Data and diagnostics (I only have Action log set at the moment), this error does not seem to occur.